# Not sure how to configure this text color change in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

This here is a block card-
[image][Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anushkas/add195)

'No Filter Selected' changes with the state of a variable:

```
const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState('');
```

I am trying to display the value of this variable in place of 'No Filter Selected' with textinput. For instance, if user inputs 10 in filter box, 10 will be shown in place of 'No Filter Selected'.

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: '#C71585', borderRadius: 10, width: 160, height: 100, marginLeft: -660, marginTop: 50}}>
    <TextInput
      numeric
      placeholder="No filter selected"
      placeholderTextColor = "#FFFFFF"
      value={filterLimit}
    />
     </View>
```

The placeholder is set to white color. I want to set the value '{filterLimit}'to also display in white color. Is there any way to accomplish that?
I have tried setting styles 'color' property to white, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to remove space around `=` in `placeholderTextColor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<TextInput
      numeric
      placeholder="No filter selected"
      placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
      value={filterLimit}
      onChangeText={text => setfilterLimit(text)} // add this
      style={{color: "#ffffff"}}
/>
```